# Can I share Google Keep notes between people?

Tags: google-keep

Is there a way to share the notes of Google Keep between different persons? For example, could I link the notes to the todos of Thunderbird Lightning, or can I share the notes between two different Google Accounts?

Comment: No, neither the Android app nor the Web interface will let you do that. Frankly, you're better off with the established sharing tools of, say, a Google Document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still think that this would be a nice features but at least I know now that I am not too stupid to find the right settings.

Comment: I think it's a design goal of all Google products to keep it simple. Simply use Google Drive if you want that feature.

Comment: Since Google Keep doesn't currently support collaborating on notes, you can also try [Cozi Family Calendar & Lists](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cozi.androidfree&hl=en) for sharing notes. It's also [available on iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cozi-family-organizer/id407108860?mt=8).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now, yes:
[Google Keep: Share ideas with friends and family](http://officialandroid.blogspot.ca/2014/11/google-keep-share-ideas-with-friends.html)

Each note now has a share button you can use to share it. More info:
[Share & collaborate in Google Keep](https://support.google.com/keep/#6101196)

Comment: It's a step forward, but not quite enough for me. I want to be able to share groups of notes, even future notes I haven't created yet if they are added to a shared group. Think Trello's Boards and Organization feature.  An organization is made up of people and boards of notes. A board of notes can have extra people added to it that aren't in the organization.

Answer (score 7):

Currently there is no way to share notes on Keep in the same way that you can share a document.

However, if your goal is to share notes between a fixed amount of persons (e.g. family members,) you can always create a new Google account, add it to all Android phones that you need to share on, and enable sync of Keep only on that account.

Comment: Well, that's one way of doing it!

Comment: Yes, I already thought about doing that, but hoped for a cleaner way.

Comment: It works quite well for sharing of other content as well, such as apps, books, music, and other media purchased via Google Play store that generally cannot be shared between different accounts.  You just have to remember to keep an eye on the Play Store during purchasing, to make sure you are buying from such a "shared" account.  Just keep the account between few users (yourself and your spouse for example,) and you won't risk Google coming down on you for sharing (which is against TOS, as far as I know.)

Comment: @fabee Keep is a fairly new service, so it's quite possible that this feature will be added in the future.  After all, other documents on Drive have had sharing features for a while, so it only makes sense for Google to add them to notes as well.

Comment: Yes, I never give up the hope :)

Comment: In [Google's initial blogpost about Keep](http://googledrive.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/google-keepsave-whats-on-your-mind.html) they stated, "You can access, edit and create new notes on the web at http://drive.google.com/keep and **in the coming weeks you'll be able to do the same directly from Google Drive.**" - so hopefully we will have the same sharing functionality soon.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Wunderlist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wunderkinder.wunderlistandroid), they have a great IOS and Android app that does it. I know some people who use it and they really seem in love with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the app has an inbuilt functionality to share to your Google+ profile etc
Update to the latest version if you haven't seen the option.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. However, I don't want to share the note itself with other persons (such that we can edit it both).

Comment: Like a note that both of you can edit? Not sure if Google Keep can do it. Evernote Premium users have this feature though.

Comment: Hmm, that that would be a great feature to include ... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give [ShareNOTZ](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sharenotz.sharenotz&hl=en) a try.  It lets you share notes, lists, and reminders,and of course it keeps your own notes synchronized between all your devices.  Full disclosure:  I'm the developer.  As such I'd love any feedback you may have.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please confirm what relationship (if any) you have with this app: it's OK to recommend your own app on this site, provided you're honest about it.

Comment: Looks like the app no longer exists.