# Can't share in Google Keep via the app, only via the webpage

Tags: google-keep

[As you know](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43436/can-i-share-google-keep-notes-between-people), since late 2014 Google Keep allows sharing notes with others.

But I've noticed I can't share in Android (tried in Samsung Galaxy S4 mini GT-i9195i) with another Gmail account. There's a save confirmation with a "viewing shared note" message, but it doesn't actually share. As if I never shared in the first place. It also doesn't auto-fill when I start typing the other Gmail account.

As soon as I try it via Google Keep's webpage, it works flawlessly. It auto-fills the other other Gmail account and actually shares with it.

Any idea why?

Comment: Is the Gmail sync on?

Comment: I mean check the Sync settings within Gmail app

Comment: If you mean Google (Gmail is not related to Keep), than yes.